# Does artifactory provide proper build info for files which are not binaries?

Tags: maven, artifactory, devops, jfrog-mission-control

I have been uploading maven web projects artifacts with Jenkins CI to artifactory.

There is a .pom file along with the .war artifact.

Images

1. [For .pom file for first version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iotqm.png)
2. [For war file of first version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56CJl.png)

We can see that pom file "produced by" column displays total build info  and for "war" it points accurately which build produced it.

So is there a way out to know who has created the .pom file?

My interest lies in knowing the details about non-artifact files(here it's a .pom it can really be anything from .txt to .zip!)

Comment: As you already mentioned the linked build ? In theory it can be a `.txt`or of course you can create a zip via Maven...But the question is what you have in mind?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am planning to keep track of the jenkins builds which deployed .net projects in zip format. As my requirement is to maintain amalgam of maven and .net projects in artifactory.

Comment: For .net Projects you should nuGet which is supported by for example Nexus....seemed to be a better choice than the Maven repository for .net components..

Comment: Thanks for the reply @khmarbaise. The issue comes for web apps in .net they are not bundled into a nuget package. As nugets are for class libs like dll's. Whereas for html css etc i have to maintain separately not like WAR in java

Answer (score 0):

For "non arti-facts" as you mentionned (zip, html, mp4,...) you can use the JFrog cli to resolve things from artifactory as dependencies and publish them as generated artifacts and then publish the build information oject generated by the cli to artifactory. You can have a look to the documenatation here : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-CollectingBuildInformation